# Azure Conditional access policy device filter rule syntax with parentheses

Tags: azure-policy

I created a policy to filter out devices that contain certain attributes. In a set, the devices should be filtered with these values:

**device.deviceOwnership -ne "Company" -and device.trustType -ne "AzureAD" -and device.isCompliant -ne True**

and in the second set this value should be filtered:

**device.trustType -ne "ServerAD"**

These two sets should be represented in a rule that looks like this:

device.deviceOwnership -ne "Company" -and device.trustType -ne "AzureAD" -and device.isCompliant -ne True -or device.trustType -ne "ServerAD"

Each set works as intended, but as soon as I use both, the filtered devices no longer work. I think Microsoft doesn't handle the operators correctly. Actually the rules should be written like this

(device.deviceOwnership -ne "Company" -and device.trustType -ne "AzureAD" -and device.isCompliant -ne True) -or device.trustType -ne "ServerAD"

The brackets are recognized in the role builder but are deleted after clicking "Apply".

[Condition for device filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cTO9.jpg)

How do I have to write the rule so that the filter applies either set one or set two?

Comment: I would recommend to create an Azure support ticket to have official support engineers assist you. They might be able to provide a workaround or confirm if this is a known issue with the syntax.